# How I can join two by two column using shell

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have 10 column in my entry, for example, and I want my output with 5 column. More specifically, I wanted to join columns 1 and 2, columns 3 and 4, columns 5 and 6, so on.

My input like as:

```
ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 
ID02 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
ID03 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 
ID04 5 0 5 0 5 2 1 2
```

And I wanted my input like as:

```
ID01 12 01 20 10 
ID02 10 10 10 10 
ID03 21 02 10 21 
ID04 50 50 52 12
```

For do this, I tried: 
`perl -alne 'print join "", $F[0], split(" ", $F[1])' data`
But I do not known how to split by two to two character/column. My real data have a hundred of thousands of column.

Comment: You mean you just want to remove every second space from each line of your file?

Comment: @terdon Yes!! I did not think this logical idea. But it is what I want to do.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, I want to keep the 1st and pair the others. But in my real data I have a hundred of thousands columns. I put an example of my data!

Comment: @AmandaBotelhoAlvarenga - as shell script or as perl script ? - what would be better to you ? arrays or determinants ? I think with determinants you would be able to manage huge datas with your thousands of columns. Commata are case-sensitive.

Comment: @dschinn1001 Both is better for me. But I usually use shell script for file editing. I am sorry, but I do not know the difference between arrays and determinants. But, if you think is better with determinants, I agree you! I only work with big data, my study is at genomic. (thank you for your attention)

Comment: @AmandaBotelhoAlvarenga - here is a link where a solution for deteminants is shown at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589805/read-value-in-matrix-in-shell-script

Comment: @dschinn1001 I will see. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove every other space:

```
perl -pe 's/ (\S+) / $1/g'
```

- `\S` stands for "not whitespace".

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $1, $2 $3, $4 $5, $6 $7, $8 $9 }' /path/to/input
```